# Dockerized web-service does not run in background even with detached flag

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to Dockerize a web service using [Tangelo](https://github.com/Kitware/tangelo) and python.

My project structure is as follows:

```
test.py
requirements.txt
Dockerfile
```

`test.py`

```
import ...
def run(query):
    ...
    return response
```

`requirements.txt`

```
... # other packages, numpy, open-cv, etc
tangelo
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python python-pip git

EXPOSE 9220

ADD . /test
WORKDIR /test
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD "tangelo --port 9220"
```

I build this using

```
docker build -t "test" .
```

And run in detached mode using

```
docker run -p 9220:9220 -d "test"
```

But `docker ps` shows me that the docker stops almost as soon as it has started. I don't know what the problem is since I cannot inspect the logs.

I have tried a lot of things but I still can't figure this thing out.

Any ideas? If needed, I can provide more info.

EDIT:

When I build, step 8 says

```
Step 8/8 : ENTRYPOINT tangelo --port 9220
 ---> Running in 8b54841853ab
Removing intermediate container 8b54841853ab
```

So it means these are run in an intermediate container. Why is that and how can I prevent it?

Comment: ENTRYPOINT and COMMAND don't actually run anything. They just add metadata to the generated image so docker knows what to run on container start. This gets propagated down through any intermediate containers generated during a build.

Comment: @avigil Interesting! First time docker user here ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Use:

```
CMD tangelo -np --port 9220
```

Instead of:

```
CMD "tangelo --port 9220"
```

---

**Explanation:**

You have two ways to debug the problem:

1. Inspect the logs of the container:

   ```
   $ docker run -d test
   28684015e519c0c8d644fccf98240d1465acabab6d16c19fd59c5f465b7f18af
   $ sudo docker logs 28684015e519c
   /bin/sh: 1: tangelo --port 9220: not found
   ```
2. Instead of running in detached mode, run in foreground with `-i`/`--interactive` (and optionally also `-t`/`--tty`):

   ```
   $ docker run -ti test
   /bin/sh: 1: tangelo --port 9220: not found
   ```

As you can see from above, the problem is that `tangelo --port 9220` is being interpreted as a single argument. Split it by removing quotes:

```
CMD tangelo --port 9220  # this will use a shell
```

or use the "exec" form (preferred, given that you don't need any shell features):

```
CMD ["tangelo", "--port", "9220"]  # this will execute tangelo directly
```

or even better use `ENTRYPOINT` + `CMD`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["tangelo"]
CMD ["--port", "9220"]  # this will execute tangelo directly
```

After this change, you'll still have a problem:

```
$ sudo docker run -ti test 
...
[29/Apr/2018:02:43:39] TANGELO no such group 'nobody' to drop privileges to
```

Tangelo is complaining about the fact that there is no user and group named `nobody` inside the container. Again, there are two things you can do: add a `RUN` to create the `nobody` user and group, or run Tangelo with the `-np`/`--no-drop-privileges` option:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["tangelo"]
CMD ["--no-drop-privileges", "--port", "9220"]
```

It's fine if during the build you see intermediate containers: Docker creates them for each build step. The commands you specify in `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` are not executed during build, they're just recorded into the final image.

Comment: Okay, thanks. This, however, did not get the thing running. Having it run in the foreground shows Tangelo's debug logs, along with a cryptic line `TANGELO no such group 'nobody' to drop privileges to`. Not sure whether this causes the thing to shut down.

Comment: Would it make a difference if I re-built with cache disabled?

Comment: Lastly, I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but the ENTRYPOINT and CMD commands are run inside an intermediate container during build and are discarded soon after.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: you can tell tangelo not to change user to `nobody` using `-np`: `CMD ["tangelo", "-np", "--port", "9220"]`

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to do anything for me. Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it does work for me. Can I see your full Dockerfile and `docker run` command?

Comment: Sure. Here it is. http://dpaste.com/2B2VT38. And my docker run is `docker run -p 9220:9220 -ti "test"` Stay tuned, I'm rebuilding with --no-cache.

Comment: Okay, I got your command working after I removed the ENTRYPOINT command, instead doing a docker run bash, going into the docker, and manually running the command.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: `ENTRYPOINT tangelo` => `ENTRYPOINT ["tangelo"]` (I know, it's hard to spot and it bites me every time too)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your patience.